# Почему при применении функции .split() появляется лишний элемент в списке?

Tags: python, функции, split

День добрый! Подскажите почему при применении функции `.split()` появляется лишний элемент в списке?

Код:

```
x = "Где это? Когда это? Кто это?"
z = x.split("?")
print(z)
```

Результат:

```
['Где это', ' Когда это', ' Кто это', '']
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Никакого "лишнего" элемента нет. Метод `split()` делит строку по разделителю, т.е. берёт кусок строки и слева, и справа. В вашем конкретном случае справа от последнего знака вопроса находится пустая строка.

Ещё более простая ситуация:

```
"?".split("?")
```

Вернёт:

```
['', '']
```

Answer (score 1):

потому что после `?` в конце строки не идет никакого символа, однако `split` разбивает строку на ДО разделителя и ПОСЛЕ разделителя - а после разделителя ничего нет, вот и получается строка нулевого размера

если сделать:

```
print("??".split("?"))
```

но получите 3 пустые строки - `['', '', '']`, потому что

```
"[тут пусто]?[тут пусто]?[тут пусто]"
```

чтобы избавиться от этого можно сделать так:

```
res = [block for block in text.split('?') if len(block) > 0]
```

конечно останутся пробелы/табуляции и т.д., но чтобы без них выделить текст, можно сделать так:

```
res = [block.strip() for block in text.split('?') if len(block.strip()) > 0]
```